# How to make call to a function which is in an external js file?

Tags: javascript, function, call, external

How to make call to a function which is in an external js file?

**Note :** here the external js file will be loading asynchronously.

**HTML file :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        (function (e, b) {
                     var a, f, i, g;
                     a = e.createElement("script");
                     a.type = "text/javascript";
                     a.async = true;
                     a.src = "http://example.com/a.js";
                     f = e.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
                     f.parentNode.insertBefore(a, f)
             })(document, window.d || []);
            </script>
```

**External js i.e. a.js :**

```
 var d = function () {
     d.prototype.init = function () {
         alert("test1");
     } ; };
```

i am not able to call init method from the html file. when im calling `d.init();` i am getting an error like init is not a function. Please let me know how make call to these kind of methods.

Comment: is your file being add to your page BEFORE you execute this script?

Comment: You could wait for the script to be loaded and `init` property on `d` be available before you call it. check this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Answer (score 0):

Your file is not probably not loaded by the time you make your call. If you used something like jQuery's getScript to load your external file, you would have a success function, and it would be safe to call your init function from there.

```
$.getScript( "externalfile.js" )
    .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
        d.init();
    })
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following handler to your code:

```
a.onload = function () {
    new d().init();
}
```